# escape quotes while passing to extjs grid

Tags: extjs, tcl

I am passing the following to my extjs grid.
how do i escape if there any quotes inside the varaible.

```
append rval "'description':'$description',"
append rval "'short_description':'$shortDescription',"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could use [regsub](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm) to substitute all the single quotes e.g.

```
regsub -all "\'" $rval "\\\'" rval  
regsub -all "\"" $rval "\\\"" rval
```

The first line will place a backslash in front of every apostrophe in the rval variable. The second line will place a backslash in front of every double quote. You have to escape the apostrophe, the double quote and the backslash itself in the regsub command too, hence the triple backslash in the 2nd last argument to regsub

Answer (score 1):

[`string map`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M39) is the simplest answer:

```
% string map {' \\'} aaa'bbb'ccc
aaa\'bbb\'ccc
```

Comment: If you're doing this a lot, it helps to write a helper procedure so that you wrap it up perfectly every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple javaScript's replace method use it like this and use following regex.

```
var tempvariable = yourJsonString.replace(/(')/g, "&#39;");
```

pass this temp variable to your grid it will work fine.